# How I Do Filter Data in ComboBox Vb.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOma9.jpg)I need help about that I have some country names in `Combobox`. I want like a first show from (A) then show from (B) like alphabetic order.

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC1-PC;Initial Catalog=Test2;Integrated Security=True")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from Table_6", connection)
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
Dim table As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(table)
ComboBox1.DataSource = table
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Country"
```

[image]

Comment: So do you want to filter the data or sort it?  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, including details of your attempt(s) to solve it.  What you have provided is too vague.

Comment: dear i have ad sql server column in combobox now i want all the words which start from a they show first second show the word of b

Comment: @SamuelLiew I would have suggested that earlier but the OP doesn't have enough points for chat.

Comment: Moderator has moved the discussion to Chat but I don't think you have enough reps to participate in chat. Sorry. Discussions that go on too long are moved.

Comment: What i Do now solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of your countries. Then sort the list and add to combobox.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim Countries As New List(Of String) From {"Cabo Verde", "Ecuador", "Haiti", "Iraq", "El Salvador", "Djibouti", "France", "Bahrain",
   "Cameroon", "Guinea", "Albania", "Finland", "Italy", "Jordan", "Grenada", "Dominica"}
    Countries.Sort()
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(Countries.ToArray)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

OKay, I am calling the field you are interested in `"CountryName"`. I am assuming it is the second field in the table which is index `1`.

The `Using...End Using` statements ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. You don't need a `DataAdapter`; just load the `DataTable`.

The best approach to getting the list sorted is to let the database do the work by adding an `Order By` clause.

```
Private Function GetCountryNames() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC1-PC;Initial Catalog=Test2;Integrated Security=True"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Tabel_6 Order By CountryName;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub FillSortedCountriesCombo()
    ComboBox1.DataSource = GetCountryNames()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName"
End Sub
```

If, for some reason, you need to do the sort in code then...

```
Private Sub FillUnsortedCountriesCombo()
    Dim dt = GetCountryNames()
    Dim CountriesArray = (From row In dt.AsEnumerable
                          Order By row.Field(Of String)(1)
                          Select row("CountryName")).ToArray
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(CountriesArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204044/discussion-on-answer-by-mary-how-i-do-filter-data-in-combobox-vb-net).